# Using Q with Node-Mysql

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, q, node-mysql

I am relatively new to Node but I have had good success with porting over RESTful API that was previously done in PHP.  There is quite a bit of database interaction and as a result I have found myself getting into what I believe many people call "the pyramid of doom" due to the async nature of Node.

As a result I am taking a stab at implementing promises using the Q library but I haven't had much success yet and am still getting null result sets back when I believe I should be getting data.  Below is my current structure before adding Q, if anyone could advise on how to correctly implement Q for this I would be able to run with that example and convert the rest of the database/memcached calls over to that model.

```
// helper function to get a company row
getRow = function(lookUp, callback) {
    var query = db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE lookUp = ?', lookUp, function(err, result) {
        var count = Object.keys(result).length;

        if(count == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}

// function that uses the above helper method
insertItem = function(request, response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.body.data);
    var message = data.message;
    var lookUp = data.lookUp;

    security.verifyToken(lookUp, function (lookUpError) {
        if (lookUpError) {
            var errorResult = { "response": "error", "msg": lookUpError };
            response.json(errorResult);
            response.end();
        } else {
            getRow(lookUp, function (companyError, row) {
                var companyId = row[0].id;

                var res = helper.insertFeedItem(companyId, message, function (insertError, insertResult) {
                    var result = (feedError) ? { "response": "error", "msg": insertError} : insertResult;
                    response.json(result);
                    response.end();
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is being able to do something like:

```
var result = getCompanyRow(lookUp);
companyId = result.company_id;
```

Again, any insight into how to best implement Q (or just promises in general) for this case would be extremely appreciated.

*** EDIT:

Here is what I have tried thus far to implementing Q, but as I said I am getting nothing back.

```
function getRow(id) {
  var dfd = Q.defer();
  var query = db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE lookUp = ?', id, function(err, result) {
    if(err) { dfd.reject(err); }
    else { dfd.resolve(result); }
  });
  return dfd.promise;
}
```

The above is not working at all when called as result = getRow(id);  I tried using Q.all and binding the function to that but I also got nothing back when trying that approach.  I wasn't sure what to include in my call to .then() but I tried a number of things, none were successful.

Comment: A `getRow` that maybe never call its `callback` is a bad idea even without promises. At least do a `callback(nothingFoundError)`

Comment: Could you please also show us your approach of using promises?

Comment: @Bergi Added.  Very crude I know but it is all I have left after a few rounds of trial and error.

Comment: That `getRow` function looks quite good - `result` will be the promise object. How have you used it in `insertItem`?

Comment: @Bergi I think the problem is how I an trying to use it in insertItem.  I wanted to do something like var result = getRow(id);  Result is an object but not the object I am expecting.  How do I go about using that object? Do I need to use .then() in the call inside of insertItem()?

Comment: Yes, `result` is the promise object on which you would call the `.then()` method. The callback that `then` takes will be given the object with which you `resolve()`d your deferred.

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately I am not getting to where I had hoped and it appears as though it is impossible. I don't see any benefit to using .then(function ...) because it still requires nesting just like a callback would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getRow` promise function looks promising :-) It can be further simplified by using the [node adapter methods from `Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks):

```
function getRow(id) {
    return Q.nfcall(db.query,    'SELECT * FROM table WHERE lookUp = ?', id);
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // or   .ninvoke(db, "query", … if it must be called as a method
}
// or even just
var getRow = Q.nbind(db.query, db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE lookUp = ?');
```

---

> I don't see any benefit to using .then(function ...) because it still requires nesting just like a callback would.

The benefit (apart from easier error handling) comes from chaining multiple tasks, i.e. when also your `security.verifyToken` and `helper.insertFeedItem` methods would return promises. If they don't (and you can't modify them) you still can use `Q.nfcall` as in the example above. Assuming they did, your code can be simplified to

```
function insertItem(request, response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.body.data);

    security.verifyToken(data.lookUp).then(function(/* no lookupError */) {
        return getRow(data.lookUp); // potentially catch SQL errors here
    }).then(function(row) {
        return helper.insertFeedItem(row[0].id, data.message);
        // What was the `res` it had returned before?
    }).catch(function(someError) { // lookUpError, companyError, insertError
        return { "response": "error", "msg": someError };
    }).done(function(result) {
        response.json(result);
        response.end();
    });
}
```